# How do I keep repeating "if"s?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want my if function to keep repeating on python when it falls onto else. How do I do that? I've added an example of my code.

```
if selection1 == "C": 
  print("Ok") 
elif selection1 == "E": 
  print("Ok") 
elif selection1 == "Q": 
  print("Ok...") quit() 
else: 
  selection1 == print("The character you entered has not been recognised, please try again.")
```

Comment: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/loops.html , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm - has pretty pictures too

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you meant this but this program does exactly as what your question asks

```
while True:
  selection1 = input("Enter Character\n")
  if selection1 == "C": 
    print("Ok") 
  elif selection1 == "E": 
    print("Ok") 
  elif selection1 == "Q": 
    print("Ok...") 
    break 
  else: 
    selection1 == print("The character you entered has not been recognised, please try again.")
```

The program takes in characters as inputs and checks them with the hardcoded characters. If not matched it will ask for the user to repeat until the letter `Q` is matched. An output can be

```
Enter Character
C
Ok
Enter Character
E
Ok
Enter Character
v
The character you entered has not been recognised, please try again.
Enter Character
Q
Ok...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible approaches

```
while True:   # i.e. loop until I tell you to break

    selection1 = GetSelectionFromSomewhere()

    if selection1 == 'C':
        print('Okay...')
        break
    elif selection1 == 'E':
        print('Okay...')
        break
    elif selection1 == 'Q':
        print('Okay...')
        quit()
    else:
        Complain()
```

Some purists dislike `while True` loops because they don't make it explicit what the looping condition is at first glance. Here's another listing, which has the advantage of keeping `break` statements and other housekeeping out of your `if` cascade, so you can focus on the necessary actions there:

```
satisfied = False
while not satisfied:
    selection1 = GetSelectionFromSomewhere()
    satisfied = True
    if selection1 == 'C':
        print('Okay...')
    elif selection1 == 'E':
        print('Okay...')
    elif selection1 == 'Q':
        print('Okay...')
        quit()
    else:
        Complain()
        satisfied = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:    
    n = raw_input("\nEnter charachter: ")
    if n == "C" OR n=="E" OR n=="Q":
        print("Ok !")
        break  # stops the loop
    else:
        n = "True"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while selection1 != "Q":
    if selection1 == "C": 
        print "Ok"
    elif selection1 == "E": 
        print "Ok"
    else:  
        print " Chose again"
print "quit"
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
characters = {'C','E','Q'}
def check():
    ch=raw_input("type a letter: ")
    if ch == q:
        quit()
    print "ok" if ch in characters else check()
    check()
```

But you have already your answer from the previous posts. This is just an alternative.